# Heart BPM Normalization - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two .wav files containing recordings of two different hearts so with different heart rates. I would like to normalize both signals in order to fix their BPM at 60 without modifying anything else.

This is how a signal is read (same thing for the other but with 2) and what it looks like (and it's FFT) :

```
[y1,fs1] = audioread(heartbeat1);
    N1 = length(y1);
    t1 = linspace(0, N1/fs1, N1);
```

[image]
I made some research and found `interp1` but it doesn't seem appropriate for my program. I really have no idea of how I could do that, so if you can just give a function that I could use it could be great.

Comment: You can do an [`fft`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html), use [`findpeaks`](http://mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) to find the heartbeat and then [`resample`](http://mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/resample.html) the signals. If you can upload a small example file, it makes it easier for us to write a complete answer.

Comment: did you try to use an adimensional frequency?

Comment: I don't think the FFt allows me to find the heartbeat. 
What's an adimensional frequency ?

Comment: As mentioned a example file would be of great use here. i dont think you want to nomalize" bc i think that would be changing the amplitude: You want to stretch the curve in the time axis so that the heartbeat goes to 60BPM right?

Comment: @Finn Yes exactly. And by exemple file you mean the .wav file ?

Comment: try to plot the signal in function of frequency/hearth beat frequency

Comment: @A_C I don't get it. If you want I can provide you the audio file so you can have an idea : http://www.partage-fichiers.com/upload/9eax6dln

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understood.

I think you want to compare two heart beat signals with different "principal" heart beat frequencies. So I think you can plot the two signals as function of

> f / f_{beat}

where f_{beat} is the heart beat frequency of a signal. This will be an adimensional (it has no units,because 1/s / 1/s = 1) frequency and should permit you to compare signals with different heart beat frequencies because it does not distort it.

This is more or less the effect of what I propose. Note that I do not know to calculate the heart beat frequency and I just used f_{beat}=0.8 1/s. Probably you can improve that.

Signal as function of frequency:

[image]

Signal as function of the adimensional frequency:

[image]

Hope this helps somehow.

Comment: Like @Finn said I want to stretch the curve in the time axis so that the heartbeat goes to 60BPM for both signal, and I don't see how `f / f_{beat}` might help

Comment: because if you use f_beat=60BPM then you know that it goes to 1, for every signal. i do not think that streatching signals is a good way to compare them

Comment: I don't want to compare them, I want them to have the same BPM on both signals. Let's say for exemple the first one has 79BPM and the second one 94BPM, I want to keep the same signal but with 60BPM. I don't know if it's clear ..

Comment: I do not see the difference. But maybe you would like better to  [pad](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html) your signals. But I am not sure on the possible code implementation

Comment: again. If you use f_beat=60BPM for both signals I think it will be equivalent to what you try to achieve.